# pattern matching on CSV file

Tags: python, string-matching

I have a Cisco router configuration file from which I want to filter specific lines and save them to an output file.
For example: if the line beggins with "interface" of if the line beggins with "ip address", then i want that line to be saved to an output file.
The following piece of basic code prints the entire contents of my file; I would need to know how to add the "if" piece of code to achieve what i am looking for:

```
import csv
with open('CORE011.txt', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=' ')
        for row in reader:
        print(' '.join(row))
```

Any hints will be greatly appreciated
Rogelio (from Argentina)

Comment: Hm, if space is the delimiter (really?), then `ip` and `address` will be put into subsequent columns, unless they are quoted. Are they?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the CSV module if you're not doing anything with it?

The simplest way would be

```
with open('CORE011.txt') as file, open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("interface") or line.startswith("ip address"):
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Come to think of it, if your CSV file contains quoted fields that have newlines in them, this method might not work correctly. Is that the case?